# How do I store data from a server when not using redux

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native. I have a journaling app that, to date, has been a web app built in rails.

A user has many journal entries.

When they login to the app, I want to pull all of their previous entries and display it to them. My question is this:

when they login and I pull all of their past entries, where do I store it?

If I store it in local storage on the phone, my concern is that some users have thousands of entries and I'm not sure if that's the appropriate thing to do.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend saving thousands of entries to a local storage, why don't you save the first few items, maybe 20 or less using local storage? or you can use SQLite (https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) . Even on SQLite I wouldn't recommend saving thousands of data there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the data to persist? You can pull the data only each time they need it instead, an effective way of doing this for thousands of records is to implement lazy loading AKA "infinite scrolling". This allows you to pull a defined number of records when they are needed and then load more when the user scrolls beyond the records that are provided initially.

There's an article [Implementing an Infinite Scroll In React Native](https://frontside.io/blog/2016/12/15/building-infinite-scroll-in-react-native.html), which walks you through an example of how to do just that